# Does DOMParser always returns normalized document? (node.normalize)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domparser

Does DOMParser always returns normalized document?

Spec says:

> The parseFromString(str, type) method must run these steps, depending on type: "text/html": Parse str with an HTML parser, and return the newly created Document. (...)

I could not find any information whether `Document` is normalized by default or not.

_

To clarify, by saying "normalized" I mean the form after an execution of a `normalize` method:

> node.normalize()
>
> Removes empty Text nodes and concatenates the data of remaining
>   contiguous Text nodes into the first of their nodes.

Sources:

https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-domparser-parsefromstring

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-normalize

https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#document

https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-normalize

Comment: A DOM from newly parsed HTML should never have empty or contiguous text nodes. The `.normalize()` is for putting your text nodes back into a state that you'd find them as though the document had just been parsed.

Comment: @squint What do you mean by _"empty or contiguous text nodes"_?

Comment: @guest271314: The same thing that is meant by the quoted docs. An empty text node is a text node with no content, and contiguous ones are adjacent text nodes each with a fragment of text. These come up when you've done some DOM manipulation then ends up emptying or fragmenting the nodes.

Comment: @guest271314: Yes. [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0xfbxwfj/) In the first one, we empty the first text node, and then call `.normalize()` on its parent and it gets removed. In the second one, we remove the `span` that separates 2 text nodes, and then call `.normalize()` on the parent and it joins the 2 text nodes into 1.

Comment: @squint Ok. Was not aware of this. Curious about expected result of _"A DOM from newly parsed HTML should never have empty or contiguous text nodes."_ ; should text node at https://jsfiddle.net/0xfbxwfj/1/ be removed from `document.body` by `DOMParser()`? Or, is this Question OP is asking?

Comment: Note that the current DOM spec is at https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/, and that’s the one that should always be consulted for any questions about what the currently defined standard is—because https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ is the only DOM spec that’s actually being maintained and updated with bug fixes, etc. All other DOM specs are just historical at this point.

Comment: @guest271314: It should be included in the creation of the DOM since it's not an empty text node. Any space characters are characters just like any other.

Comment: @squint What would be considered an empty text node?

Comment: @guest271314: When the DOM is parsed, there will be no empty text nodes, because if there's no text, there's no need to create a node. An empty text node only comes about if you manually create an empty one... `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""))` or if you empty an existing one... `document.body.firstChild.data = ""` *(assuming the `firstChild` is a text node)*.

Comment: ...or if you use some of the text node methods that could result in an empty one. I've rarely used those, so I'd have to look them up to give an example.

Comment: @squint What is Answer to OP's Question? Though still not clear, here, about what OP is actually asking; appears, as you indicated at first comment that the string would not have any "empty" nodes, as input is string, not `document` where `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""))` or `document.body.firstChild.data = ""` could be used? Though could have space characters which would be preserved

Comment: @guest271314: The answer, to my knowledge, it that there would be no need for `.normalize()`. However, that doesn't necessarily mean that an implementation wouldn't go rogue and put empty nodes all over the place, or split up text into multiple, adjacent nodes. I don't know that there's anything in the spec that would prevent it, but it seems very unlikely and, for me, not worth researching. So it comes down to if this is a practical issue for the OP to pursue. If there's some reason that demands this be guaranteed, then the OP may just need to walk the DOM and normalize all elements.

Comment: ...but I think we would've heard of reports of this happening by now if this actually took place.

Comment: another quicker useful way to parse an html string is `new Range().createContextualFragment(s)`

Comment: The discussion is very interesting and satisfying. @squint please write an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @rzymek: I'd encourage you go ahead and post an answer that is the accumulation of what you discovered both here and from your own research and testing. I usually just engage in conversations in comments and leave the answers to others.